# How to cast or convert numeric to varchar data type on sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

```
DECLARE
    @k numeric,
    @acc numeric
SET
    @k = 651393561522 ,
    @acc = 1231234560
WHILE (@k < 651393563552)
    BEGIN
        SET @k = @k + 1 ,
            @acc = @acc + 1
        insert into recipients (id, client_id, inn, name, bic, bill, version)
        VALUES(@k, 1, @acc, 'clientid'+ cast(@k as varchar), 300335, 'bill'+cast(@acc as varchar), 1)
    END
```

Have such errors:

> [42000][257] Implicit conversion from datatype 'NUMERIC' to 'VARCHAR' >is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
>
> [42000][257] Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'VARCHAR' is >not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: so why you don't use CONVERT instead of CAST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages mention ***implicit*** conversion errors so this would tend to rule out the ***explicit*** conversions being performed by the `cast()` calls.

This leaves us with datatype mismatch issues for the other columns/values; OP will want to doublecheck the datatypes of the `recipients` columns:

- the 1st error message mentions `numeric to varchar` and since the only numeric values are `@k` and `@acc`, I'm guessing either the `id` or `inn` column is defined as `varchar`
- the 2nd error message mentions `integer to varchar` and since Sybase (ASE) treats `1` and `300335` as integers, I'm guessing either the `client_id`, `bill` or `version` column is defined as `varchar`